# Reinitializing a jQuery plugin after DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-plugins

I'm using a [jQuery plugin](http://webtrendset.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html) which organizes my content into vertical tabs.

Some of my tabs are hidden at page load and should show depending on the value of a Drop-down. My issue is, when I'm trying to load the tabs on change of dropdown (basically I `.show()` the tabs and its content and reinitialize the plugin), the content shows up all in one tab and doesn't work perfectly.

Please check the example created at [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/IzAgejo/3/edit?html,output) to know what I am speaking about.

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Please check the link I posted above, all the code's there. Should I post some of the main code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it simply

```
function checkPlan(plan) {
        if (plan == 'Basic') {
            jQuery('li.premService').hide();
            jQuery('li.premPlusService').hide();
        } else if (plan == 'Premium') {
            jQuery('li.premService').show();
            jQuery('li.premPlusService').hide();
        } else if (plan == 'Premium Plus') {
            jQuery('li.premService').show();
            jQuery('li.premPlusService').show();
        }
    }
```

Error is : you have to show only the tab so here I have added `li` on the selector `li.premService`,`li.premPlusService`.....

WithOut `li` it will get all the elements which have the class `premService` ...

demo : http://jsbin.com/IzAgejo/4/edit

Comment: Wow! That makes so much sense!! Wonder what was I thinking... Thank you so much :)